# Make span reactive to a textarea of an AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, textarea

I have the following code: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vucigesesi/1/edit?html,console,output):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
<body>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.Name = "John";
    });
  </script>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="Name"><br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="myText" ng-model="Name"></textarea>
  </div>

  <span id="fromQuery">to override</span>

  <script>
    $("#myText").on("change keyup paste", function() {
      console.log("changed");
      var x = document.querySelector('#myText');
      console.log(x.textContent);
      document.querySelector('#fromQuery').innerHTML = x.innerText
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to realise two things:

1) the change to `input` should impact `textarea` and vice-versa, this has been already realised by AngularJS.

2) the change to `textarea` (either due to the change of `input` or from manual modifications) should impact the `span`. It does not work at the moment, the property `textContent` or `innerText` or `innerHTML` does not work.

Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Additionally, will it be a better practice to integrate the onchange event into `myApp` as well?

Comment: Changes to the input or textarea will affect the span cause both the controls are bound to one model property. Why don't you move the span inside your controller scope and just use the `{{Name}} ` in place of `to override`

Comment: I am very new to AngularJS. Actually at the place of `span`, I have a big procedure. So I am wondering if it is a OK practice to separate this procedure from the AngularJS app, and fire the procedure by an onchange event of the textarea.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to exclude "span" from the Controller scope ?

Comment: I made `span` as an example; actually I have a lot of code that is reactive to the change of the textarea. Now I need to wrap the `input` and `textarea` in a AngularJS controller, so I am wondering what to do with that initial "lots of code".

Comment: Are you loading all that initial code from any other source ? or how is it done ? If that is written by you, you can have it all in the controller scope and create a model object to manipulate their values based on the text-area value.

Comment: It is written by me. And there are other `onchange` events (which are irrelevant to this textarea). Additionally, some of the code uses jQuery (is it a problem?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is never use JQuery or angular.element() for DOM manipulation inside controllers.
Controllers are only used for our business logic.
We can use service, factory, $scope, value, constants etc inside it.

**Bad Way -**

We can do it with JQuery -
but please don't do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<body>
    <script>
    var name = '';
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.Name = "John";
      name = $scope.Name;
      $scope.$watch('Name', function(newVal, oldVal){
        name = newVal;
        console.log(name);
      });
    });
  </script>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        Name: <input id="name" type="text" ng-model="Name"><br>
        <br>
        <textarea id="myText" ng-model="Name"></textarea>
    </div>

    <span id="fromQuery">to overrided</span>

    <script>
    $("#myText, #name").on("keyup", function() {
      console.log("changed");
      document.querySelector('#fromQuery').innerHTML = name;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Good Way -**

Here all things in myCtrl controller-

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
<body>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.Name = "John";
      $scope.overrideName = 'to override';
      $scope.getName = function(){
        $scope.overrideName = $scope.Name;
      }
    });

  </script>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="Name" ng-keyup="getName()"><br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="myText" ng-model="Name" ng-keyup="getName()"></textarea>

    <span id="fromQuery" >{{overrideName}}</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working,:-

```
document.querySelector('#fromQuery').innerHTML = x.value;
```

Comment: indeed, it works... So is it a OK practice to put **outside** something reactive to the change of an element of a Controller?

Comment: No, because even if you move the span inside the div it will still display the value in the label, because the textarea and label are being manipulated by the jquery script independent of angular [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/mewibesoru/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the change in text-area to reflect in span do a watch on the text-area model. Before that , include the span tag inside your controller scope and assign a model variable to it like below:

**Html** :

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     Name: <input type="text" ng-model="Name"><br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="myText" ng-model="Name"></textarea>
    <span id="fromQuery" ng-model="spanValue">to override</span>
</div>
```

**Controller** :

```
$scope.$watch("Name", function () {
  $scope.spanValue = $scope.Name;
});
```

Comment: My present code does not use jQuery **inside** the Controller, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I just checked that and was editing my answer again. Yes you didn't use in your controller.

Comment: Why did you use the span tag outside the controller scope ? It is good to take advantage of angular directives , instead of including separate scripts.