# Read AngularJS expressions in a script outside the controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Because of the following quote in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41003294/6330767)

> The best practice is never use JQuery or angular.element() for DOM manipulation inside controllers. Controllers are only used for our business logic.

I have moved a big function that calls `CodeMirror` and `JQuery` outside a controller. The big function is used to combine the content of two textareas. [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tolewoz/8/edit?html,js,output)

Html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <textarea ng-model="area1">area1</textarea>
  <textarea ng-model="area2">area2</textarea>
  <div>First: {{area1}}, {{area2}}</div>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script>
    function bigfunction(area1, area2) {
      // a big function, the following is for the sake of simplicity
      return "Second: " + area1 + ", " + area2
    }
    var output = bigfunction({{area1}}, {{area2}});
    $("#output").html(output)
  </script>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.area1 = "initial textarea1";
    $scope.area2 = "initial textarea2"
});
```

Does anyone know why `{{area1}}` and `{{area2}}` in the script are not recognised?

Comment: I think you can't use `bigfunction({{area1}}, {{area2}})` in javascript.

Comment: `$("#output").html({{area1}})` in the script does not work either...

Comment: Yes. Check the answer below. I think that will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing JavaScript with AngularJS templates.

```
var output = bigfunction({{area1}}, {{area2}});
```

You cannot expect inline JavaScript to work using AngularJS templates. Here's what happens: the HTML file (template) is loaded and the inline JS is parsed and executed. It fails because it contains erroneous syntax (`{{area1}}`). This occurs before AngularJS is even loaded. Also, JavaScript code is evaluated but once, so even if the template actually replaced the `{{area1}}` with a string, the code would not be reevaluated and would not produce a different output. You will need to change your approach entirely.

I'm guessing that you would like to perform the joining of the two scope variables outside the controller and perhaps add extra logic to that. You can either move the code to a service and then use it in your controller, or use a directive (I don't know your exact use case, so it's hard for me to say which approach will make more sense).

Since what you described is simple concatenation of two model values, a directive appears to make sense. Your HTML could look like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <textarea ng-model="area1">area1</textarea>
    <textarea ng-model="area2">area2</textarea>
    <div>First: {{area1}}, {{area2}}</div>
    <output area1="area1" area2="area2"></output>
</div>
```

And in the JS, add this simple directive:

```
app.directive('output', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="output">Second: {{area1}}, {{area2}}</div>',
        scope: {
            area1: "=",
            area2: "="
        }
    };
});
```

If for some reason you wish to add extra logic to your directive, you can always do that in the linking function.

Were you to add a service, the HTML would again require only a minor change:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <textarea ng-model="area1">area1</textarea>
    <textarea ng-model="area2">area2</textarea>
    <div>First: {{area1}}, {{area2}}</div>
    <div>{{output}}</div>
</div>
```

And the JS could look like this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, joiner) {
    $scope.area1 = "initial textarea1";
    $scope.area2 = "initial textarea2";
    $scope.$watchGroup(["area1", "area2"], function() {
        $scope.output = joiner.join($scope.area1, $scope.area2);
    });
});
app.service('joiner', function() {
    this.join = function(a1, a2) {
        return "Second: " + a1 + ", " + a2;
    };
});
```

The service can contain any logic you need.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I put the two JSBins here ([directive](https://jsbin.com/tolewoz/17/edit?html,js,output), [service](https://jsbin.com/hasofag/3/edit?html,js,output)) for the record.

Answer (score 0):

the `script` tag seem to have no access to angular vars. See [Pass Angular scope variable to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960622/pass-angular-scope-variable-to-javascript) to check for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$scope.area1 = "initial textarea1";
$scope.area2 = "initial textarea2";
function bigfunction(area1, area2) {
  // a big function, the following is for the sake of simplicity
  return "Second: {{area1}} {{area2}}" 
}
var output = bigfunction($scope.area1, $scope.area2);
$compile(angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#output')[0]).html(output))($scope);
```

or you can try directive like this:

```
app.directive('outputDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
         scope: {
            area1: "=",
            area2: "="
        },
        template: '<div>Second: {{area1}}, {{area2}}</div>'    
    };
});
```

All the best.

Comment: Do you mean putting `bigfunction` inside `app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) { ... });`? This is not what I want to do...

Comment: You can do it there only. If you really don't want to do that in controller, move that to a directive instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<script>
    window.onload=function bigfunction() {
    var area1=angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="myCtrl"]')).scope().area1;
    var area2=angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="myCtrl"]')).scope().area2;
    result= "Second: " + area1 + ", " + area2;
    $("#output").html(output);
}
</script>
```

You can retrieve the angular js scope variable in javascript in this way.